# Split a string with where number comes

Tags: python, string, split

I have this string

```
a = "IN 744301 Mus Andaman & Nicobar Islands   01  Nicobar 638 Carnicobar 9.2333  92.7833 4"
```

I want to to split this with regular expression where ever number has come, the output would be like this

```
['IN' , '744301', 'Mus Andaman & Nicobar Islands', '01' , 'Nicobar', '638', 'Carnicobar', '9.2333','92.7833', '4' ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lookahead and lookbehind:

```
import re
a = "IN 744301 Mus Andaman & Nicobar Islands   01  Nicobar 638 Carnicobar 9.2333  92.7833 4"
new_a = re.split('(?<=\d)\s+|\s+(?=\d)', a)
```

Output:

```
['IN', '744301', 'Mus Andaman & Nicobar Islands', '01', 'Nicobar', '638', 'Carnicobar', '9.2333', '92.7833', '4']
```

Regex explanation:

`(?<=\d)\s+`: matches any whitespace (`\s`) that is preceded by a digit (`\d`).

`\s+(?=\d)`: matches any whitespace followed by a digit.

`|`: applies either joined expression that has a match.

Comment: could you elaborate this  regular expression.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` by a number-like pattern and then `findall` by the same pattern. Since `split` and `findall` are "sister" functions, you will get both non-numeric and numeric pieces. Now, zip them into a single list and eliminate spaces.

```
from itertools import chain
# You can improve the regex to cover numbers that start with a .
NUMBER = r'\d+(?:\.\d*)?'  
combined = chain.from_iterable(zip(re.split(NUMBER, a),                                                        
                                   re.findall(NUMBER, a)))
result = [x for x in map(str.strip, combined) if x]
#['IN', '744301', 'Mus Andaman & Nicobar Islands', '01', 'Nicobar',
# '638', 'Carnicobar', '9.2333', '92.7833', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with a group (capturing parenthesis) to keep the delimiters (the numbers) in the result:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "IN 744301 Mus Andaman & Nicobar Islands   01  Nicobar 638 Carnicobar 9.2333  92.7833 4"
>>> re.split(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', a)
['IN ', '744301', ' Mus Andaman & Nicobar Islands   ', '01', '  Nicobar ', '638', ' Carnicobar ', '9.2333', '  ', '92.7833', ' ', '4', '']
```

Comment: could you elaborate this regular expression.. Thanks

Comment: Try it on regex101.com